# Workaround for Multiple Inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have to implement classes to transfer files to USB (`class USBTransfer`) and over FTP (`class FTPTransfer`). Since both the classes use some common methods (like getting the filename, reading some parameters etc.) so, I have implemented those methods in an another class (`class FileOperations`). I have inherited both the classes (i.e. `class USBTransfer` and `class FTPTransfer`) from the `class FileOperations`.

```
class FileOperations
{
    protected void CommonMethod1();
    protected void CommonMethod2();
}

class USBTransfer : FileOperations
{ 

}

class FTPTransfer : FileOperations
{

}
```

**PROBLEM:** During the file transfer operations, I set different states (not using the state machine design pattern though). I want to use a **ABSTRACT** class for this purpose with the following structure.

```
abstract class FileTransferStateMachine
{
    //Public
    public enum FileTransferStates { Idle = 0, FileCopyingState = 1, SuccessfullyCopiedState = 2 }
    public static FileTransferStates CurrentState = FileTransferStates.Idle;

    abstract protected void IdleState();
    abstract protected void FileCopyingState();
    abstract protected void SuccessfullyCopiedState();
}
```

But in C# it is not allowed to have multiple inheritance.

**QUESTION:** I know that I can use interface. But you cannot have variables and in that case both of my classes (i.e. `class USBTransfer` and `class FTPTransfer`) will have their own variables for the following

```
public enum FileTransferStates { Idle = 0, FileCopyingState = 1, SuccessfullyCopiedState = 2 }
public static FileTransferStates CurrentState = FileTransferStates.Idle;
```

I want to reduce redundancy and want to force to have same variables/methods (hmm...same methods can be achieved by interface) for the state machine.

**Question PART-2:** I can transfer files to USB or FTP as mentioned above but both the transfer operations have some common states like `IdleState`, `FileCopyingState` or `SuccessfullyCopiedState` which have their corresponding methods (i.e. `IdleState()`, `FileCopyingState()` or `SuccessfullyCopiedState()`). I want to **FORCE** both the classes to implement these methods (i.e. `IdleState()`, `FileCopyingState()` or `SuccessfullyCopiedState()`). If any class forgets to implement any method then, I should get a compiler error. Basically, the `FileTransferStateMachine` should be an interface/abstract class whose methods should be overridden in `USBTransfer` and `FTPTransfer` classes (which are already inheriting another class called `FileOperations`).

Comment: Why use `static` here? Also why is `FileTransferStates` a nested type? Remove those things and turn it into an interface add another layer in the hierarchy chain.

Comment: `FileTransferStates` is `static` because this variable is read in an another class and by declaring it to be static, I don't need to have an object to access this variable in another class.

Comment: "... is static because this variable is read in an another class": ouch.

Comment: I agree with Igor, but additionally, surely a FileOperation **is not** a state, it **has** a state. So add a field ’private FileTransferStateMachine state’ to FileOperations, define some public getter, and you are good to go

Comment: @HugoRune: Could you please add a little sample structure for the `USBFileTransfer` and `FTPFileTRansfer` classes. I am feeling completely lost. I understood the answer of "Henk Holterman" below about using Composition. But I am confused how do I force the implementation of methods declared in `FileTransferStateMachine` (i.e. IdleState(), FileCopyingState() etc. ) ? I am confused how to properly utilize the Composition `FileOperations` as structured in "Henk Holterman".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use composition (and avoid `static` state members) :

```
abstract class FileOperations
{
    protected void CommonMethod1();
    protected void CommonMethod2();

    protected FileTransferStateMachine Statemachine { get; set; }
}
```

---

Edit, regarding Part 2:

When you want to force the concrete classes to implement each of those methods then an interface `IFileTransferStateMachine` is exactly right.

You could also derive FileOperations from the StateMachine:
`abstract class FileOperations: FileTransferStateMachine {  }`

but I would use an interface, it can be applied more granular.

Comment: If I declare `FileTransferStateMachine Statemachine` as protected (and not static) then, how can I read the value of this variable in an another class (that class is just reading the value and publishing corresponding messages about the state).

Comment: The `protected` level was just a guess from my side, make it public. But you shouldn't need `static`, and you can't use it when 2 file operations are running simultaneously.

Comment: thanks, everybody is saying that `static` should not be used here. Could you please add some points about the negative effects of using a `static` in this case.

Comment: @skm Henk did: `you can't use it when 2 file operations are running simultaneously` - in other words, when you create 2 instances of your class then your code won't work since you will have a single (static) value for 2 instances.

Comment: You seem to want to follow best practices with modeling and abstract classes. But a public static field is a global state nightmare. A practical point: that 'other class' could see what's happening but only for 1 file at a time. No way to find out what file. So give it a reference t the running FileOp in a decent way.

Comment: @Maarten, Henk: Thanks for the explanation. In my case, I am restricting to have only one file operation (one transfer to USB) at a time so, that's why I didn't get this problem.

Comment: It's still a bad design. And it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: `Fileoperations` class should be Composition and how about `FileTransferStateMachine` class? Should it be an Interface?

Comment: It could implemented as both, not decidable from the given context. Without the need for DI a class looks good enough.  But making it an interface would solve the static issue very well.

Comment: In my original post, I mentioned that I want to force the implementation of all the file transferring states methods in both the classes (i.e. USBFileTransfer and FTPFileTransfer). But just by using the Composition, I don't get any error if I don't implement any method in `USBFileTransfer ` or `USBFileTransfer `.

Comment: Add that to your question (as a Part 2). Be clear about what you want exactly, I'm losing track here.

Comment: What would the workaround be if your classes were actually just fields not methods? If you're going to say properties I've considered that.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing both of the parts you say are a problem:

- `FileTransferStates` can be moved out of the class, placed directly in the namespace (probably in its own file). Then it can be used by both implementations without being redefined
- `CurrentState` can be made a non-static **property** (not field). Properties can be put on an interface, so they don't need an abstract class. Properties are highly recommended over fields for public members anyway, and as others have said, static isn't appropriate here.

As others have mentioned, another option is to use one of these two classes as a dependency instead of a base class. I.e. using composition instead of inheritance.